# BlocBuilder not rebuilding UI even after sending different state class and implementing Equatable properly

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

So I am facing a weird issue with my BLoC, I am facing a UI rebuild issue in my state. I am trying to rebuild my UI , but it is not doing anything. I know there are some questions already asked here about this issue, but these are not similar to my case. I am triggering an event and calling an API to receive some data, I am being able to receive the data properly as well, when I emit the state of a similar class, I am not being able to update my UI. I have already added all the variables in the props array for my state class and upon using the debugger, I can see that previous state class and new state class is different. Yet I am not being able to update my UI.

here are the state classes

```
class DashboardScreenInitial extends DashboardScreenStates {
  DashboardScreenInitial(super.stateNotifier, super.startDate, super.lastDate,
      super.formattedStartDate, super.formattedEndDate);

  @override
  List<Object> get props {
    return [
      super.startDate,
      super.lastDate,
      super.formattedStartDate,
      super.formattedEndDate
    ];
  }
}

class DashBoardScreenLoading extends DashboardScreenStates {
  DashBoardScreenLoading(super.stateNotifier, super.startDate, super.lastDate,
      super.formattedStartDate, super.formattedEndDate);

  @override
  List<Object> get props {
    return [
      super.startDate,
      super.lastDate,
      super.formattedStartDate,
      super.formattedEndDate
    ];
  }
}

class DashboardScreenLoaded extends DashboardScreenStates {
  ResponseBusinessSummary responseBusinessSummary;
  List<ShiftTerminalSaleData> shiftOrTerminalWiseCollection;
  String shiftTerminalCollectionTitle;
  int selectedSaleDateList;

  DashboardScreenLoaded(
      this.responseBusinessSummary,
      this.selectedSaleDateList,
      this.shiftTerminalCollectionTitle,
      this.shiftOrTerminalWiseCollection,
      String startDate,
      String endDate,
      String formattedStartDate,
      String formattedEndDate,
      int stateNotifier)
      : super(stateNotifier, startDate, endDate, formattedStartDate,
            formattedEndDate);

  @override
  List<Object> get props {
    return [
      super.startDate,
      super.lastDate,
      super.formattedStartDate,
      super.formattedEndDate,
      responseBusinessSummary,
      selectedSaleDateList,
      shiftTerminalCollectionTitle,
      shiftOrTerminalWiseCollection
    ];
  }
}

class ShiftTerminalListChanged extends DashboardScreenStates {
  ResponseBusinessSummary responseBusinessSummary;
  List<ShiftTerminalSaleData> shiftOrTerminalWiseCollection;
  String shiftTerminalCollectionTitle;
  int selectedSaleDateList;

  ShiftTerminalListChanged(
      this.responseBusinessSummary,
      this.selectedSaleDateList,
      this.shiftTerminalCollectionTitle,
      this.shiftOrTerminalWiseCollection,
      String startDate,
      String endDate,
      String formattedStartDate,
      String formattedEndDate,
      int stateNotifier)
      : super(stateNotifier, startDate, endDate, formattedStartDate,
            formattedEndDate);

  @override
  List<Object> get props {
    return [
      super.startDate,
      super.lastDate,
      super.formattedStartDate,
      super.formattedEndDate,
      responseBusinessSummary,
      selectedSaleDateList,
      shiftTerminalCollectionTitle,
      shiftOrTerminalWiseCollection
    ];
  }
}

class DashBoardLoadError extends DashboardScreenStates {
  ResponseBusinessSummary responseBusinessSummary;

  DashBoardLoadError(
      super.stateNotifier,
      super.startDate,
      super.lastDate,
      super.formattedStartDate,
      super.formattedEndDate,
      this.responseBusinessSummary);

  @override
  List<Object> get props {
    return [
      super.startDate,
      super.lastDate,
      super.formattedStartDate,
      super.formattedEndDate,
      responseBusinessSummary
    ];
  }
}
```

here is the method I use to fetch data and emit states,

```
_getBusinessSummary(
      GetBusinessSummary event, Emitter<DashboardScreenStates> emit) async {
    var startDate = event.startDate ?? "";
    var endDate = event.endDate ?? "";
    var formattedStartDate = event.formattedStartDate ?? "";
    var formattedEndDate = event.formattedEndDate ?? "";
    int stateCount = event.stateCount;
    emit(DashBoardScreenLoading(stateCount,startDate, endDate, formattedStartDate, formattedEndDate));
    try {
      stateCount++;
      var response = await _fetchBusinessSummaryFromApi(startDate, endDate);
      if (response != null) {
        if (response.flag!) {
          List<ShiftTerminalSaleData> shiftTerminalWiseCollection = response.shiftWiseCollection!;
          String shiftTitle = "Shift Wise Sales";
          emit(DashboardScreenLoaded(response, 0, shiftTitle,
              shiftTerminalWiseCollection, startDate, endDate,formattedStartDate,formattedEndDate,stateCount));
        } else {
          var errorResponse = ResponseBusinessSummary(
              flag: response.flag, messageBag: response.messageBag);
          emit(DashBoardLoadError(stateCount,startDate, endDate,formattedStartDate,formattedEndDate, errorResponse));
        }
      } else {
        var errorResponse = ResponseBusinessSummary(
            flag: false, messageBag: "An Error Occurred!Please Try Again!");
        emit(DashBoardLoadError(stateCount,startDate, endDate,formattedStartDate,formattedEndDate, errorResponse));
      }
    } catch (e, stacktrace) {
      Utils.debugPrint(e);
      Utils.debugPrint(stacktrace);
      var errorResponse = ResponseBusinessSummary(
          flag: false, messageBag: "An Error Occurred!Please Try Again!");
      emit(DashBoardLoadError(stateCount,startDate, endDate,formattedStartDate,formattedEndDate, errorResponse));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of rendering UI as well?

Comment: code where UI is being renderd - https://pastebin.com/HAUxgtjV

Comment: Update! It was a silly mistake on my end , I have multiple instances of the BLoC declared and instead of fetching the already declared BLoC which was responding perfectly , I was trying to read the state from another BLoC instance.

Answer (score 1):

1. At these lines can you please print out the state to make sure it goes through all expected states:

```
        child: BlocBuilder<DashBoardBloc, DashboardScreenStates>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            print(state.runtimeType);   /// this prints to console
            return _dashboardScreenBody(state);
          },
        ),
```

2. In _getBusinessSummary, when emitting new state, you reuse the startDate, endDate, formattedStartDate, ... instead of getting new value from the API, so the display like this won't update:

```
[
  Text(state.formattedStartDate),
  const Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
  Text(state.formattedEndDate)
]
```

3. When creating bloc, you right away add the event

```
final DashBoardBloc _bloc = DashBoardBloc()
    ..add(GetBusinessSummary(-2,
        startDate: Utils.getInstance().startDate,
        endDate: Utils.getInstance().endDate,
        formattedEndDate: Utils.getInstance().formattedEndDate,
        formattedStartDate: Utils.getInstance().formattedStartDate));
```

so the state of DashboardScreenInitial won't last until the widget get rendered. But in your UI, the loading screen is based on DashboardScreenInitial state.

```
            state is DashboardScreenInitial
                  ? const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
```

4. Sometime the API call locally on development is way too fast for us to realize any changes but only seeing the final result.
5. I would suggest breaking down your UI into multiple Widgets, each is for one section if possible. Because we can use BlocBuilder in multiple places and refine based on buildWhen clause and smaller part is easier to troubleshoot. Currently it's too complex and I really don't see which will emit ShiftTerminalListChanged.

Comment: Okay to clarify, instead of creating all the widgets in one place, I create separate widget classes and use separate blocs. That makes sense.